# How to fix this code in Scheme, where I am trying to find the last two elements in the list

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write a code in scheme -last_two(lst) where it should output the last two elements in the list.

```
(define (last_two lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '() )
  (if (null? (cdr lst))
      lst)
  (if(null? (cddr lst)))
      lst)
  (last_two (cdr lst)))

last_two(1 2 3 4) -> (3 4)
```

Comment: You're also not calling `last_two` correctly. Functions are called `(funcname arguments)` not `funcname(arguments)`. It should be `(last_two '(1 2 3 4))`

Answer (score 2):

A procedure returns the value of the last expression that's executed in the body. In your procedure, when one of the first `if` conditions is true, you don't return the value from the procedure, you just go on to test the next condition. Eventually you get to the end, which is the recursive call -- you never stop at the base case. Eventually you'll get an error when you try to call `(cdr lst)` on an empty list.

You can use `cond` to test a series of conditions and return the value from the first one that's true.

Also, you should be returning `lst` when the conditions match; your code will always return `()`, since you're returning the same thing that matched the `null?` condition.

```
(define (last_two lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        ((null? (cddr lst)) lst)
        (else (last_two (cdr lst)))))
(last_two '(1 2 3 4))
```

You might notice that the first 3 conditions all return `lst`, so you could combine them using `or`.

```
(define (last_two lst)
  (if (or (null? lst) (null? (cdr lst)) (null? (cddr lst)))
      lst
      (last_two (cdr lst))))
```

Comment: why do we have #t in the last line of the first code?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `else`.